# Found unsuitable Qt version "5.12.4" from C:/Qt/5.12.4/msvc2015_64/bin/qmake.exe when configuring Eigen 3.3.7 using CMake

Tags: qt, cmake, qt5, qt4, eigen3

Environment:

- Windows 10 version 1903, 64 bit
- CMake 3.15.3
- Qt 5.12.4
- Eigen 3.3.7
- Visual Studio 2015 Update 3

Issue:

When I run `cmake -G"Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" ..` in `build` folder created in Eigen 3.3.7 root folder, I got the following error message:

> -- Found unsuitable Qt version "5.12.4" from C:/Qt/5.12.4/msvc2015_64/bin/qmake.exe
>
> -- Qt4 not found, so disabling the mandelbrot and opengl demos

I have googled for days but the articles are either about other platforms or do not work. For example, I have double checked that the PATH environment variable is properly set so that `where qmake` returns correct path. So, how to make Eigen 3.3.7 happily work with Qt5 when configuring it using cmake (including the mandelbrot and opengl demos), or Eigen3 does not work with Qt5 at all, only with Qt4? I would be surprised if the latter is the answer because Qt5 has been there for nearly a decade. If that is the case, is there any plan for Eigen3 developers to support Qt5 in near future? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like the demos have barely been touched in recent years. I don't think it should be hard to make them Qt5 compatible. Feel free to file an issue or provide a patch/pull request. Eigen itself does not use/depend on Qt, this is just a demo application.

Comment: Thanks, I'll ignore the error. So the error is because the mandelbrot and opengl demos are built exactly on Qt4, so their CMakeLists.txt files have to check Qt4 specifically, right?

Comment: @user5280911 While not too far apart, Qt 4 and Qt 5 are still different enough, that they are not directly source compatible (well, unless you use enough #ifdefs and avoid many nice Qt 5 features). So generally app is either Qt 4 or Qt 5, and not both.

Comment: The [Qt4 test](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/default/demos/CMakeLists.txt) is performed only for the demos (and you may disable it with -DEIGEN_TEST_NOQT=1).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can scroll down to the configure options and select qt version, as shown in the following figure:

[image]